# Overload resolution with universal reference involved

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, language-lawyer

For the following code:

```
class A {};

template <typename T> void f(T& a) {}
template <typename T> void f(T&& a) {}

int main() {
    A a;
    f(a);
}
```

clang++ binds the call to the first overload, while g++ reports ambiguous call.  Which one is taking the correct action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both gcc 4.9.0 20140302 and clang 3.5 (trunk 202594) correctly pick the first version. As [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) kindly gave me [the references in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248157/overload-resolution-with-universal-reference-involved#comment33789898_22248922):

- It was a subtle issue, there was [a defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1164),
- The gcc implementation prior 4.9 implemented the earlier defect, see  [Template overload resolution ambiguous for `T&&` versus `T&`](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57172)
- The corresponding part in the standard is **14.8.2.4 [temp.deduct.partial]**, paragraph 9:

> If, for a given type, deduction succeeds in both directions (i.e., the types are identical after the transformations above) and both `P` and `A` were reference types (before being replaced with the type referred to above):
>       — if the type from the argument template was an lvalue reference and the type from the parameter template was not, the argument type is considered to be more specialized than the other; otherwise,
>       — if the type from the argument template is more cv-qualified than the type from the parameter template (as described above), the argument type is considered to be more specialized than the other; otherwise,
>       — neither type is more specialized than the other.

---

By the way, watch [The Universal Reference/Overloading Collision Conundrum](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5swP3dr190) video why overloading on universal references is a bad idea. In short, consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A { bool guts_stolen; };

void steal_guts(A&& a) {
  a.guts_stolen = true; 
}

template <typename T> void f(const T& a) { 
                          // ^^^^^ note the const!
  std::cout << "T&\n"; 
}

template <typename T> void f(T&& a) { 
  std::cout << "T&&\n";
  steal_guts(std::move(a));
}

int main() {
    A a{ false };
    f(a);
    std::cout << "Guts stolen? " << std::boolalpha << a.guts_stolen << std::endl;
}
```

If you run the program, it will print

```
T&&
Guts stolen? true
```

which is not at all what you would expect just by looking at `A a{ false }; f(a);`.

Comment: Both the first version, with `T = A`, and the second version, with `T = A &`, have a parameter of type `T &`, so on what basis can you say that it is correct that the first version gets picked? (I do think you're right, but you should really explain your answer.)

Comment: @hvd Yes, I am trying to find the corresponding section in the standard / a gcc bugreport in bugzilla.

Comment: [Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1164) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57172) :)

Comment: @hvd Thanks!!! I will add it in a minute and an example showing why overloading on universal references is a bad idea.

Comment: @goodbyeera OK, added the references, please check. Sorry it took a little longer than expected...

Comment: @Ali: Why say sorry :-)  Thank you very much for this complete answer and the complementary example.

Comment: So in this example the `T&&` overload gets picked because the `T&` version is more cv-qualified, ie. it would only pick that for a const reference in case both overloads are present?

Comment: @TamásSzelei Yes, it only picks the `const T&` version if the argument is `const`. That's why it is usually a bad idea to overload on `T&&`.